# Ellipse application problem. I am not sure where to begin with this problem. Is there an easier way of doing this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

> An express way is built in the shape of a semielliptical arch and is to have a span of one hundred feet.  The height of the arch, at a distance of forty feet from center, is ten feet.  Find the height of arch at the center.

Comment: What difficulties did you encounter while attempting to solve it?

Comment: Hint: Given $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. if $a = \frac{100}{2} = 50$ and you know $x$ and $y$, then what is $b$?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $|AC|=L=100$, $|OA|=|OC|=\tfrac12L$,
$|OE|=d=40$, $|BE|=h=10$.

Consider a circle $\mathcal C$ through the endpoints of $AC$ centered at $O$,
with the radius $\tfrac12L$.
The extension of the line $EB$ intersects with the circle $\mathcal C$
in $D$. Let $|BD|=g$, then $k=\frac h{h+g}$
is an $y$-scaling factor that transforms
the circle $\mathcal C$ into the sought ellipse through $A,B,C$,
and its height $H$ at the center is then $k\cdot\tfrac12L$.

So, first, we need to find $g$.
By the Stewart’s theorem,

\begin{align}
\triangle DOE:\quad
|OE|^2\cdot|BD|+|OD|^2\cdot|BE|
&=|DE|\cdot(|OB|^2+|BD|\cdot|BE|)
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\triangle BOE:\quad
|OB|^2&=d^2+h^2
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}
and it follows that
\begin{align} 
g&=\tfrac12\,\sqrt{L^2-4d^2}-h
=20
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
k&=\tfrac13
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
H&=\tfrac{50}3
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}